# FDA and WCF Interoperablity Proof

Tags: wcf, standards-compliance, interop

How do I prove to the FDA that WCF is interoperable? Is there a document describing their test procedures? Or, is it common knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

WCF if interoperable but it's difficult, and not all interoperation paths are as secure as others.

If you like, here is a list of all interoperable protocols supported by WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx

Ultimately, the problem isn't WCF, which adheres to the standards I linked very well, but non-WCF systems that *do not* adhere to the standards properly. In general, I find the OASIS standards the most secure for interoperability, and WCF handles those superbly via the Ws2007HttpBinding.